# Minor formatting issue when a question has > 10,000 votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was browsing the [forums](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/) at cplusplus.com, and I noticed user Greywolf had answered one of my questions there.
I thought I had seen the name before over on Stack Overflow, so [I searched for user 'Greywolf'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3AGreywolf), and found a *minor* page formatting issue:

[image]

This bug is limited to questions in Search which have a score of 10,000 or more.

This is with the latest Chrome on Windows 8.1 on a full HD screen (1920x1080).

I appreciate that *every* bug cannot be fixed, but I thought I'd report it in the case that it *does* get fixed.

*Edit*:

Nice to see that the new design has this bug fixed.

Comment: You can't use the `user:` search with a username; it only takes a user **id**, and is meant to limit search results to posts with that user id as the author; you cannot use a username in that case because usernames do not need to be unique. As such `user:Greywolf` is ignored as invalid, and you end up with an empty search matching everything in the site. Search for users on the [*Users* tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users), there is a search box there.

Comment: Search for [all users matching the term *Greywolf*](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=greywolf).

Comment: Rolled back to the original bug-report.

Comment: Yup, just pointing out why your search returned all results on the site, and addressing just that side issue, all in comments and not an answer. :-)

Comment: It seems that the stats box is sized nicely for a max of 4 digits. Even on [the page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yPdMd.png) it looks too big.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of upvotes...

Comment: It breaks here too with `1440 x 900`.

Comment: Only needs 3613 downvotes...

Comment: Same bug reported on [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214706/224428

Comment: Wow, that seems rare enough to have it just display as a centered "10k+"

Comment: Adding a warning message that *all* search conditions have been ignored may be useful.

Comment: Same issue at 1600*900, Win 8.1.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - it is an *extremely* good (and, even to a lot of people with enough experience that they ought to be able to work it out, non-obvious) answer to a *very* interesting question.